# Extending sap.m.List gives me error: ...failed to load 'sap/m/items.js'

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I tried to extend `sap.m.List` to a new custom control which i will call `MyList` here.

Right now my `MyList` does nothing fancy. Its definition looks like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/ListBase"
], function (List) {
  "use strict";
  return List.extend("companyname.control.MyList", {
    metadata : {
      defaultAggregation : "items",
      aggregations: {
        items: {type: "sap.ui.core.Control", multiple: true}
      },
    },
    renderer: {}
  });
});
```

But when i use it with a simple UI5 Control in `<items>...</items>`, i get this JavaScript error:

```
...failed to load 'sap/m/items.js'...
```

This happens when i use a simple Control but not with a ListItem. Even tough i told `MyList` to accept `type: "sap.ui.core.Control"` as `items`.

I think its a lack of understanding how to extend lists. But i cant find any examples for extending `sap.m.List` on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the namespace you're maintaining in the view for your control ? Say if it's

*xmlns:company = companyname.control*

then you'll have to use this namespace with your control's aggregation.

```
<company:items></company:items>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be xmlns:company = "companyname.control" ?